# Use AutoLayout to scale down UIImageView height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, uitextview

So, In my app I have an UIView (it resizes keeping the same aspect ratio so that it always touches the sides of the screen) and in that view I have an UIImageView and an UITextView on top of it. 
**Visually (the pink rectangle is the textview):**  [image]

What I want to achieve is that if the UITextView gets taller(more text is added to it), it pushes down the UIImageView's height. **Visually:** [image]

What constraints should I use or how could I achieve this using auto layout?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UITextField constraints:**
Leading space, Trailing space, Top space to UIView margins constraints + Height constraint of the textfield.
**UIImageView constraints:**
Leading space, Trailing space, Bottom space to UIView margins constraints + Top space constraint to UITextField.

Then when you change height constraint of the UITextField, your UIImageView will move down.

Comment: @BalázsVincze please make this as answer, so it will help others.